# Data explorer, questions where I did not answered

Tags: support, data-explorer

I would like to find the questions for a specific tag where does not exists an answer of mine on data explorer.

What I'm missing is how to connect a question to its answers.  I can wonder that `Posts` is used both for questions as for answers. If so, is the `ParentId` the right field to use? Is a question the parent post for an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have the table in there twice with an appropriate alias.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    posts q 
    JOIN posts a ON a.parentid = q.id 
WHERE
    ...
```

Note how the table alias `q` is for questions and `a` is for answers.

An example of this in a working query (though I do the join the other way around there) can be seen in this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/102768/marginal-short-answers